# accessing web method declared in .cs file not associated to any aspx or ascx file in ajax(jquery)

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Hi I moved a web method from code behind file of an aspx page to another cs file which is present in data section(which doesn't contain any aspx page). Previously I used to access web method by using Ajax, the url like

```
type: "post",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
url: "Results.aspx/EmployeeSummaryHistory",   // call history function
data: JSON.stringify(emp),
success: function (resp) {
```

but now I am trying to access the moved web method by using the Url

```
type: "post",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
url: "~/Model/Data/EmployeeRepository.cs/EmployeeSummaryHistory",   // call history function
data: JSON.stringify(emp),
success: function (resp) {
```

but I am getting error and I don't know how to access web method declared in .cs file which doesn't contain any aspx file associated to it please help me with this.

My web method is like

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<RefEmployee> EmployeeSummaryHistory(string empNo)
{
    var employee = new RefEmployeeRepository();
    //Employee History.
    List<RefEmployee> list = new List<RefEmployee>();
    list = employee.SummaryHistEmployee(empNo);
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Since it is not associated to any httphandler(unlike your first case where it is associated to aspx which itself is a handler) You probably would need to write a handler and register it in web.config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are called ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods for a reason, the endpoint must be `public static` methods, decorated with the `WebMethod` attribute, that are within a `Page` class or class that derives from `Page`.

Comment: then how to access methods from other cs files by using ajax? The functions which are declared in other .cs files that are not associated to any aspx page? is there any other method instead of declaring a method as webmethod in .cs file to access it?

Comment: @user2864496 - You can call your other class from within the page method that is hosted inside the .aspx page's class. I do this all the time with business methods and data-access layer (DAL) methods, both of which are separate classes inside separate DLLs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    var theWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://localhost:51045/Default.aspx/Senddata");
                theWebRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(tobj.Username, tobj.Password,tobj.propertyID);
                theWebRequest.Method = "POST";
                theWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8 ";
                //theWebRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Pragma.ToString, "no-cache");
                using (var writer = theWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
                    {
                        something = value                    
                    });

                    var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

                    writer.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                    writer.Flush();
                    writer.Close();
                }

                var theWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)theWebRequest.GetResponse();         
                var theResponseStream = new StreamReader(theWebResponse.GetResponseStream());
                string result = theResponseStream.ReadToEnd().ToString();
   var data1 = new JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(result);
```