# call difference class method using javascript or jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

Hello I have been ask this question in interview. A method exists in different class lets say

```
public class EmployeeDept 
{
  public void showNames()
  {
    //display list of names
  }
}
```

How do we call this method from javascript? if method exists on our page code behind we can call it using pagename/methodname. The interviewer ask me how can we call this method from javascript and this method is not exists in your code behind page class, it exists in different class EmployeeDept.

Comment: if it is exists in code behind page we can use this $.ajax to call the method name by passing url: pagename/methodname; but this method exists in difference class EmployeeDept.

Comment: it is not possible..the only way is to call some other method in the page which can in turn call this method 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19777020/accessing-web-method-declared-in-cs-file-not-associated-to-any-aspx-or-ascx-fil

Comment: how gave me this -1 and on what basis?? its an interview question with which i'm also confused if you're confused not able to under it that doesn't mean to give me -1

Comment: If you are familiar with Asp .net mvc it's possible from ajax "/controller/action". where the controller actually is a class and action is method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- One way would be using AJAX to do so.
- You can also write code behind method on current aspx.cs page which will call the code behind function from other page. Something like this:

  ```
  protected string CallOtherProject() {
      OtherProject.Class1 c = new OtherProject.Class1();
      //call other project method
      return c.GetInfo();

  }
  ```